# What is the difference between ways to distribute identical and different objects?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

> How many ways can we distribute 13 plants among 6 different people?

The answer is $6^{13}$ but I can't seem to differentiate it from ways to distribute among **identical** people which would be $ \binom{6+13-1}{13}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the people are identical then one arrangement is that somebody has plants 1-3, somebody else has 4, somebody else has 5-10, somebody else has 11, another person has 12-13 and someone has none.

If the people are different, say they are A,B,C,D,E,F, then this counts as $6!=720$ different arrangements, because for every ordering of A-F there is a different arrangement. A has 1-3, B has 4, C has 5-10, D 11, E 12-13 and F none is different to C 1-3, F 4, A 5-10, D 11, E 12-13, B none.

If the people are different, then for every plant there are $6$ different choices for who it can go to, and these choices are all independent, so in total there are $6\times 6\times...\times 6=6^{13}$ possibilities.

Incidentally I think the formula you give at the bottom is for identical *plants*, not identical people.

Comment: What would the answer be for different  plants?

Comment: I see, plants are identical because you can distribute them to any person. The part that I don't understand is that how it can be $6^13$ when there are only 13 plants?

Comment: For different plants but identical people, if you require each person to get at least one plant it would be the Stirling number of the second kind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind); if not then you can add up the Stirling numbers for 1,2,...6 people.

Comment: $6^{13}$ is for different plants. There are $6$ ways to deal with plant 1 (it can go to any of A-F), then $6\times 6$ to distribute plants 1 and 2 (to AA, AB,... FF - here AB is different from BA because although they both get a plant they get different plants in the two cases), and so on.

Comment: Oh I see, each plant can "choose" between 6 objects and their product is the answer!